# Encrypt and decrypt String with AES in Android

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I am new in Android and I want encrypt and decrypt one String in Android with AES 256 and I search a lot of information and any go to me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

There is a password based encryption approach that you can use. With a salt, string password and iteration count you can generate a key to initialise ciphers to encrypt and decrypt. Have a look at the library I made. You will find what you are looking for. https://github.com/rishelarora/AES256PasswordBasedEncryption-Decryption